# How to detect rare events in Time series?

Tags: classification, time-series, autoencoder, boosting

I am working on a time series dataset in which each time step can be classified under 4 classes:

- `~EOI` : `P(~EOI)` = .85
- `EOI-1`: `P(EOI-1)` = .05
- `EOI-2`: `P(EOI-2)` = .05
- `EOI-3`: `P(EOI-3)` = .05

where EOI is Event Of Interest.

Due to the huge class imbalance in `~EOI` and `EOI-X`, I planned to use the boosting technique and build 1 classifier to identify `EOI`/`~EOI` events and then a sub-class classifier which would classify the 3 EOI events.

On further inspection I fear that for `~EOI` class, there may be too much randomness and the may not have any distinguishable pattern and may just be noisy data.

I tried the Classification approach(traditional ML + NN approach), but i feel that could be set up for failure.

Another approach

1 approach that I could think of was to apply an auto encoder to do Anomaly detection. But before I invest time and effort there, i needed some opinion/advice on the same.

Please suggest alternative approaches or possible pros/cons of my current approach

Comment: This looks complicated, have you tried something simpler first?

Comment: what could be simpler??

I mean i did try binary classification